# how to apply flex-column for block only on sm-breakpoint in Bootstrap 3.3.7?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

So the general idea is - on screens less than sm size, I would use the column flex-direction; everything bigger - the row flex-direction (or, in the worst case, if it impossible, I will not use the flexbox at all):

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-centered d-block **flex-sm-row**">
 <a class="button-basic button-action btn-block btn-ajax-modal" href="/user/registration/register-ajax?origin=c-profile_print" onclick="return false;" data-origin="c-profile_print">Blabla blabla</a>
 <span style="display: inline-block;">
   <img class="icon32" src="/img/pdf-icon.png" alt="">
   <a class="fs12 add-to-basket-inner-link" href="blalbla" target="_blank">Blablabla</a>
 </span>
</div>
```

here **flex-sm-row** suppose to switch the flex-direction when screen size is wider than sm, but it doesn't

Question - how to handle this challenge?
(I can't switch to another version of Bootstrap cause it's used in plenty of places inside the whole huge project)

Comment: just create the class in CSS with a media query and then use it wherever you want

Comment: thanks, I had such idea. But hoped that there is smth. in-built in Bootstrap 3 :)

Comment: not as far as I know. There are utility classes built into BS 4.* but not on 3.3.7

Comment: got, very sad. Thanks one more time :)